# broadcast to room works on every second connection in socket.io with android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I created socket io server using nodejs and from android connected to the server.

I am using io. socket: socket. io-client: 1.0.0 library for android.

The problem was when I try to send message when open app it works. But when I reconnect socket I it not works. Just when second reconnection it works. Every second connection. Previously I tried to add users to client variable, then emit to socketid. But now I am using the rooms.

I think socket io server store old room, and for second connection it works properly

How can I refresh rooms before broadcast or broadcast last updated rooms?

server.js

```
module.exports = (httpsServer) => {
    const io = require('socket.io')(httpsServer, {
        log: false,
        cookie: false,
        multiplex: false
    });
    io.set({
        transports: ['websocket', 'polling']
    });
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {

        ocket.on('join', (id) => {
            console.log(id + " joined");
            socket.join(id);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', (id) => {
            console.log(id + " leaved");
            socket.leave(id);
        });

        socket.on('messageToUser', (endUserId, msg) => {
            console.log("admin broadcast to: " + endUserId);
            socket.broadcast.to(endUserId).emit('inbox', {
                senderId: '1',
                endUser: endUserId,
                message: msg
            });
            socket.emit('inbox', {
                senderId: '1',
                endUser: endUserId,
                message: msg
            });
        });
    });
};
```

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.secure = true;
            opts.transports = new String[]{WebSocket.NAME};
            opts.reconnection = true;
            opts.forceNew = true;
            opts.multiplex = false;
            mSocket = IO.socket("...",opts);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

ChatActivity.java

```
    App app = (App) getApplication();
        mSocket = app.getSocket();
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT,onConnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT,onDisconnect);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on("inbox", inbox);
        mSocket.connect();
sendButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!mSocket.connected()) return;
            if(!messageEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                mSocket.emit("messageToUser", endUserId, messageEditText.getText().toString()); 
                messageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!isConnected) {
                        mSocket.emit("join", userInfoSharedP.getUserId()); 
 isConnected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. I am using pm2 process manager. And I run PM2 with its built in load balancer. Something like this:

```
pm2 start server -i 2
```

And when I stop pm2 and start own node server, it works properly. I think problem in load balancing with 2 core. And when I connect socket every second connection emit works. It is because of dividing processes into two.

Firstly install redis

```
# on mac
brew install redis
sudo brew services start redis
```

Then install the socket.io redis adapter in project

```
npm i socket.io-redis --save
```

Finally,

```
const sockets = require('socket.io')
const redis = require('socket.io-redis')

const bindListeners = (io) => {
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`${socket.id} connected`)
  })
}

module.exports = (server) => {
  const io = sockets(server, {
    transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ]
  })
  // Add the redis adapter
  io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }))   
  bindListeners(io)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need background or foreground service for ChatActivity or at least asynctask , also u can use global public variable for socket instance this is needed for properly running

Comment: Can you give examples ?